# R return error using system()

Tags: r

I am trying to find out how to capture the error message from `system()`

EX:

```
> res <- system("ls home",intern=TRUE)
ls: cannot access home: No such file or directory
Warning message:
running command 'ls home' had status 2 
> res
character(0)
attr(,"status")
[1] 2
```

Is there a way to capture the "ls: cannot access home: No such file or directory" in `res`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like that, i.e. redirecting the stderr data

```
res <- system("ls home 2>&1",intern=TRUE)
```

which will result in

```
[1] "ls: home: No such file or directory"
attr(,"status")
[1] 1
```

Comment: Nice to hear that

Comment: This works for this command but what I am trying to really to is use res <- system("impala-shell -i....",intern=TRUE) and when there is a query error, capture the error. Adding  2>&1 doesn't seem to do it here

Comment: This method is not working for other errors like if the command does not exist. Any other workaround?